# System can't find specifed path ndkbuild in android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ocr

I want to build an ocr app in android.For that i am using **tessaract** library.I am following this turorial [ocr tutoial](http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/) it says follow below steps

1. Download the NDK & extract to C:\ drive-**Done**
2. Set NDK Path & Android SDK path to **PATH** variable in Enviorment Variable.-**Done**
3. Download [tessaract library](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two,) and extract it to C:-**Done**
4. open command line & go inside tessract folder ibn downloaded library.-
5. Write ndk-build-**Not Done**

When i write **ndk-build** it says `the system can't find the specified path`.
Please tell me how to resolve this issue.I have already spent lot of hard time on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure why i needed to use ndk-build.I just followed the tutorial

Answer (score 4):

If you re-read the link you posted, you may notice this line from the author:

> Attention: if you fail at any of the above steps, you are not ready for this shit yet. Better grab an introduction to android development course, read a book, then come back to this tutorial. You’ll just waste time and nerves and you’ll bitch about it in the comments that this crash, this doesn’t work. (PS. no, I will not send you the source code on your email, stop spamming k thx.)

You should seriously consider his advice - working with the Android NDK only gets more difficult from here.

---

You're probably getting that error message because cmd couldn't find the ndk-build program, which is located inside the root of android-ndk-r10e. Possible causes:

- You made an error when editing your PATH variable - make sure each file path is separated by a semicolon and that you provided the full path to your NDK install.
- Your PATH is too long - the max length is 260 characters. [See this page for more info.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath) tl;dr: prefix \?\ to your PATH to get around this length limit.
- You had cmd open when you set the variables - try restarting the cmd
  program or even restarting your machine.

Comment: Yes i have read it carefully.But it is not working means not working there is an issue which author might not have come across and just to avoid answering questions he has written stuff like that.Path is correct.It is not too long.I have verified the path by restating the system & when i write PATH command then it shows me correct path.If you can help me more it would be so great.